# Worker unable to connect to the master and invalid args in webport for Locust

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, locust

I am trying to set up a load test for an endpoint. This is what I have followed so far:

### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8

# Add the external tasks directory into /tasks
WORKDIR /src

ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade locust==2.10.1

ADD run.sh .
ADD load_test.py .
ADD load_test.conf .

# Expose the required Locust ports
EXPOSE 5557 5558 8089

# Set script to be executable
RUN chmod 755 run.sh

# Start Locust using LOCUS_OPTS environment variable
CMD ["bash", "run.sh"]

# Modified from:
# https://github.com/scrollocks/locust-loadtesting/blob/master/locust/docker/Dockerfile
```

### `run.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
LOCUST="locust"
LOCUS_OPTS="--config=load_test.conf"
LOCUST_MODE=${LOCUST_MODE:-standalone}

if [[ "$LOCUST_MODE" = "master" ]]; then
    LOCUS_OPTS="$LOCUS_OPTS --master"
elif [[ "$LOCUST_MODE" = "worker" ]]; then
    LOCUS_OPTS="$LOCUS_OPTS --worker --master-host=$LOCUST_MASTER_HOST"
fi

echo "${LOCUST} ${LOCUS_OPTS}"

$LOCUST $LOCUS_OPTS

# Copied from
# https://github.com/scrollocks/locust-loadtesting/blob/master/locust/docker/locust/run.sh
```

This is how I have written the load test locust script:

```py
import json

from locust import HttpUser, constant, task


class CategorizationUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = constant(1)

    @task
    def predict(self):
        payload = json.dumps(
            {
                "text": "Face and Body Paint washable Rubies Halloween item 91#385"
            }
        )
        _ = self.client.post("/predict", data=payload)
```

I am invoking that with a configuration:

```
locustfile = load_test.py
headless = false
users = 1000
spawn-rate = 1
run-time = 5m
host = IP
html = locust_report.html
```

So, after building and pushing the Docker image and creating a k8s cluster on GKE, I am deploying it. This is how the `deployment.yaml` looks like:

```yaml
# Copied from 
# https://github.com/scrollocks/locust-loadtesting/blob/master/locust/kubernetes/templates/deployment.yaml

---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: locust-master-deployment
  labels:
    name: locust
    role: master
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: locust
      role: master
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: locust
        role: master
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: locust
          image: gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_URI
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: LOCUST_MODE
              value: master
            - name: LOCUST_LOG_LEVEL
              value: DEBUG
          ports:
            - name: loc-master-web
              containerPort: 8089
              protocol: TCP
            - name: loc-master-p1
              containerPort: 5557
              protocol: TCP
            - name: loc-master-p2
              containerPort: 5558
              protocol: TCP

---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: locust-worker-deployment
  labels:
    name: locust
    role: worker
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: locust
      role: worker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: locust
        role: worker
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: locust
          image: gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_URI
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: LOCUST_MODE
              value: worker
            - name: LOCUST_MASTER
              value: locust-master-service
            - name: LOCUST_LOG_LEVEL
              value: DEBUG
```

After deployment, I am exposing the required ports like so:

```bash
kubectl expose pod locust-master-deployment-f9d4c4f59-8q6wk \
    --type NodePort \
    --port 5558 \
    --target-port 5558 \
    --name locust-5558

kubectl expose pod locust-master-deployment-f9d4c4f59-8q6wk \
    --type NodePort \
    --port 5557 \
    --target-port 5557 \
    --name locust-5557

kubectl expose pod locust-master-deployment-f9d4c4f59-8q6wk \
    --type LoadBalancer \
    --port 80 \
    --target-port 8089 \
    --name locust-web
```

The cluster and the nodes provision successfully. But the moment I hit the IP of `locust-web`, I am getting:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to resolve the bug?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the environment variables set by k8s is colliding with locust’s (LOCUST_WEB_PORT specifically). Change your setup so that no containers are named ”locust”.

See https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1226 for a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks. 

So, I changed the `deployment.yaml` spec to this: https://pastebin.com/5EfNgF1t. The same error happens.

Comment: Hmm. I’m not sure what it could be then. Maybe something to do with this: `kubectl expose pod locust-master-deployment-f9d4c4f59-8q6wk \
    --type LoadBalancer \
    --port 80 \
    --target-port 8089 \
    --name locust-web`

Comment: Anything in particular that doesn't look right to you?

Comment: Sorry, I’m no kubernetes expert, but it looks like it is (for some reason) setting the LOCUST_WEB_PORT env var.

Comment: Thanks. 

I ended up following: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/distributed-load-testing-using-gke. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are exposing your `pods` and you are trying to access to them outside the cluster (your web application), you have to `port-forward` them or add an `Ingress` in order to access to your `locust pods`.
My first approach will be trying to `ping` or send requests to your `locust pods` with a simple port-forward.

More infos about the port forwarding [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/).

Comment: Thanks. 

I ended up following: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/distributed-load-testing-using-gke. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @S.P, okay if it the infos sounds perfect solution you can upvote it and put as a solution so people next time can know how to solve the issue.